# What is the difference between "Source files" and "Include path" in a PHP project?

Tags: php, netbeans, path, include

What is the difference between "Source files" and "Include path" in a PHP project in NetBeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Source files** are files you write yourself as part of your project.

The **Include path** contains files that will be scanned for autocompletion and hints provided while you type. This is mostly for external libraries that you will use, but your source files are automatically included in the include path for autocompletion.

Comment: ok. if i have public folder with index.php, assets, etc., application folder (my own (php) files) and framework folder. Framework folder is under include path. How can i select multiple folders for source path when creating new project? I can't just select parent folder becouse there are other projects in the parent folder.

Comment: Can't you just move all those folders into one main folder and then include that? :)

Comment: Now, my local paths and server paths are identical so that could lead to a mess :( I know i could then change my server paths but if i start thinking that way... I cant think about my application like that. Thank you thedayturn :)